# How to use JSONObject and JSONArray class in groovy? without getting "unable to resolve class JSONObject" error on terminal

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to make a json object(from root to leaf node) and print in json format recursively from my child-sibling tree structure in groovy using JSONObject and JSONArray class but I am continously getting this  "unable to resolve class JSONObject" error . My code snippet is below :

```
void screenout(Nope roota, Map mapp) {
    me = roota;
    Nope temp = roota;
    if (roota == null)
        return;
    def rootie = new JSONObject();
    def infos = new JSONArray();
    while (temp != null) {
        def info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("category", temp.val)
        info.put("path", mapp[temp.val])
        infos.add(info);
        roota = temp;
        temp = temp.sibling;
        screenout(roota.child, mapp);
    }
    rootie.put("children", infos);

    if (me == root) {
        println(rootie.JSONString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of inputs and outputs showing what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Use proper imports and if JSONObject class is from ext lib, use @Grab to fetch the dependency first.

Comment: @tim_yates yes,

Comment: @tim_yates yes, I want the output in this form                                              [
      {
        "category": "a",
        "path": "a",
        "children": [
          {
            "category": "ab",
            "path": "a/ab"
          },
          {
            "category": "ad",
            "path": "a/ad",
            "children": [
              {
                "category": "ada",
                "path": "a/ad/ada"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]

Comment: @tim_yates so my input here roota is the root node in my tree structure where a's child is ab and ac is sibling of ab. similarly ada is the child of ad.  the next argument mapp shows mapping for each node such that a maps to a ,ab maps to a/ab, ada maps to a/ad/ada and so on

Comment: @SandeepPoonia can you suggest me the proper imports for this problem and how to use /@Grab .  I have used import groovy.json.*; and I am totally a newbie to groovy and json .

Comment: Have you looked at [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)?

Comment: yes i did , but could not come up with one such usage where i can put my objects recursively in the builder. can you suggest one ? @Steinar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given:

```
class Node {
   String category
   List children
}

def tree = new Node(category:'a', children:[
    new Node(category:'ab'),
    new Node(category:'ad', children:[
        new Node(category:'ada')
    ])
])
```

I can just do:

```
import groovy.json.*

println new JsonBuilder(tree).toPrettyString()
```

To print out:

```
{
    "category": "a",
    "children": [
        {
            "category": "ab",
            "children": null
        },
        {
            "category": "ad",
            "children": [
                {
                    "category": "ada",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , tim_yates. This was the perfect answer.

Comment: Is the suggestion here to not use `JSONArray`?

Comment: Yes. Why make it hard?